# What input and window handler should I learn for complement OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++, input

I have a good base in C++ programming and I did some 2D games using SDL. Now I want to start making 3D games, but as much as posible, I want to learn following the standars of the profesional industry. 
I think learning openGL I will have more acuratte skills for programming 3D graphics, so I prefer to study openGL instead of a game engine. But my cuestion is, what library I should choice for complement openGL in the area of the input and windows handler, if posible, following the standars of the industry?

Thanks you in advance for the help! (And sorry for my bad english)

Comment: This is a "which technology should I use" question, and there's usually no definitive answer, so everyone just ends up posting their own opinions. StackExchange tries to encourage questions that can have a definitive answer.

Comment: I don't like voting to close on a new user, but @michael.bartnett is quite correct; please don't let this put you off using the site more though.  (PS: your English is fine!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL Is a fairly good choice. Typically used in cross-platform and Open-Source Projects. Including in professional applications. Not limited to, but including  [these few SDL applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_using_SDL). Including 3D applications, with it's OpenGL binding ability.

However, a lot of professional game companies will make their own game library/engine. Creating it by learning the target system's API. And they will, in particular, learn how to create a window through that API, including how to bind OpenGL to it.

A list of those APIs for common systems are:

- Windows - WinAPI
- *nix - X windows
- Mac - cocoa